# Why is Cinnamon Bun blue?

Tags: adventure-time

In S05E47, *The Red Throne*, Cinnamon Bun is hanging out with Flame Princess in Fire Kingdom.  During the entire episode, he's blue.  No one remarks on this, nor do we see how he became blue.  Last time we saw him, he was not blue, and was serving drinks during the Apple Wedding.  Nothing in that episode caused the color change.

Why is he blue in this episode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I havent seen the episode yet, but unless there was some massive change, it is a [flame shield](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Flame_Powers#Flame_Shield) casted on him to protect him from the fire kingdom environment. At  the bottom of [this page](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Kingdom), you'll see examples of Finn and Jake with it, and they are blue (I can't link the images for some reason). [Flambo](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Flambo) casts the shield the first time (I think) it's seen in [Incendium](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Incendium).

Comment: Those images match the hue of CB.

Answer (score 3):

**Summarized answer:** Cinnamon bun turns blue in season 5, episode 32 (earth and water). He helps Flame Princess and she makes him one of her guards in fire kingdom, casting a protection spell on him.
This incantation turns the characters blue. Without it, he wouldn't survive entering the fire kingdom without getting burnt to death. Since he wasn't born in there and his body was not made to support fire.

**Here's more details of how it happened:**

**Recap/ Context** - two episodes ago (ep 30 - Frost and fire), Flame princess(FP) broke up with Finn and she's now filled with negative emotions. She is also questioning if people are really worthy of trust. Being that Finn had been recently lying to her. Creating conflict between her and the ice king just to see them fight each other. For his own entertainment. Fighting the ice king led FP to get extremely hurt and weak by the end. It put her life in danger.
Feeling guilty, Finn hurries to check on her and reveals the truth. She feels deeply betrayed and asks for space.

**How CB turned blue** - We can see flame princess, alone in the forest, pulling out handfuls of grass and burning them, out of frustration.
To her surprise, she finds princess bubblegum(PB) following her around, using a malfunctioning invisibility gadget and taking notes. When she confronts PB, the princess confesses how she sees Flame princess as a threat.
PB explains that she's conducting a study on Flame princess. And that, if the research is successful, she might find out how to control or even completely repress FP's tremendously intense and volatile emotions.
Flame princess then offers to collaborate with PB, enticed by the idea of eliminating her feelings once and for all.

At PB's lab, PB ends up tying up flame princess to a machine looking more like a torture device. FP feels apprehensive, but PB reassures FP that it will help her understand herself better.
Unexpectedly, PB picks up a call from Finn and Jake and needs to leave for a while. She leaves cinnamon bun(CB) in charge, instructing him not to open the door to the room where flame princess is and also to write down all the numbers that show up in a tiny device in front of him.
As soon as PB leaves, cinnamon bun opens the door and approaches flame princess. He tells her that she looks sad and asks if she wants to hang out at his place.

At his place, CB bumps into a table while dancing and gets hurt. Flame princess uses her heat to bake his injury, healing him.
From the moment flame princess bakes him to cure his injury, cinnamon bun becomes more articulate. He calls FP one of his friends. FP gets emotional and starts opening up about how she's feeling that friendships are full of lies.
She also tells CB how she really understands him and she wishes everyone was as easy to get.
CB then asks if FP considers PB to be her friend. FP replies that she's not sure. CB proceeds to mention PB locking up FP in "baby jail" and how that was a "weird friend thing".
FP, who had no idea PB was the one responsible for her being locked up in a jail her entire life, is shocked. She stands up, wondering if everyone around her is being deceitful and wishing everyone was as honest as CB. FP decides that she must return to where she belongs.

Back to the lab, PB takes Finn to face FP. So she can measure FP's reactions when having to look at "the person who broke her heart". Finn looks down in shame after hearing that comment. PB is excited but soon finds out that FP is gone.
PB, irritated, then takes Finn on a mission to the fire kingdom in order to find FP and finish her experiment.

At the fire kingdom they find FP, who has defeated her father and is the new ruler. She changed the law, demanding that only people who are honest remain in her kingdom and she made cinnamon bun one of her royal guards.

That's why he became blue. He had the fire protection spell casted on him so that he can remain in the fire kingdom without getting hurt.
PB orders cinnamon bun to return home. But he refuses, smiling and telling her that he finally has a real dog now. He pets a fire wolf sitting happily next to him (showing how he was never truly happy or fulfilled in candy kingdom).

**How CB was treated in candy kingdom/ why I presume he left** (this part is not relevant, just an observation) - He was never happy in there. Always very clumsy and never seemed to fit in.
For example, in season 2, episode 9 - the other tarts. The first episode where he gets to actually participate in not only as a background character(at least that I remember), we start to see a glimpse of how unhappy he truly was in Candy kingdom.
We quickly learn that he actually wants to be a guard and help princess bubblegum.
PB calls Fim and Jake for a very important mission. She explains how she needs them to take some rare tarts to a royal ceremony. She needed them to be careful, because they would face some people trying to rob the tarts. She then instructs them to use a safer path.
CB had already offered to take the royal tarts for princess bubblegum. A request that she doesn't even bothered to address, she just whispers to Finn and Jake how CB came out with a defect because he didn't fully bake when she made him. And how there was no way for him to succeed in that mission. She warns them not to let CB partake in it.
Finn and Jake look at CB and see how excited he is to help. They come up with a plan to give a bunch of poisoned tarts to cinnamon bun and send him off to deliver them, in the correct path indicated by PB, as an attempt to lure the tart robbers to attack CB instead of them. They assumed that if they took a less predictable path, they would outsmart the robbers.
Finn and Jake end up losing all the tarts they were carrying and cinnamon bun succeeds in delivering his, arriving sooner at the royal event.
Turns out CB always had the correct tarts to begin with. And thanks to him, the event was saved, as well as all the guests lives. But PB doesn't even recognize his efforts or thank him. She doesn't apologize for calling him defective and for not believing him, preventing him from following his dream job because of how he was born.
This episode only showed how CB was often underestimated and undervalued by the people in candy kingdom. He was often seen as silly and never had no one actually believe him or at least give him a leap of faith in any meaningful task.

Another example is s5 ep24, where we see PB forbidding CB from using his night light. She mentions that he's too old.
We learn that CB has an extreme phobia of the darkness and we see him panicking during the whole episode. He loses it when PB leaves him in a completely dark room and enters panic mode.
People around don't seem to care about helping him calm down.

Not to mention the episodes where CB is literally the catalyst for things going wrong in candy kingdom. Like when he ate a piece of a zombie residue that PB was using for an experiment, causing the entire candy kingdom to be turned into zombies, except for Finn.
And one of the first episodes, where he trips while dancing and bumps into PB's tower, breaking it and causing her to fall down.

It's easy to conclude that deep down he never felt like candy kingdom was his home. He struggled to fit in. His personality was never seen as useful nor convenient in there.

Answer (score -5):

He had a spell cast on him probably from flambo 
this has happened to fin and Jake when they went to the flame kingdom